# How to check if there is a match of third column with numbers with regexp in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a file that needs to be parsed and depending on if there is a match or not, I will process the file.

The file can look different, here are examples of different combinations:

```
#ROW 1234 "1111"
#ROW 1234 1111
#ROW 1234 ""
#ROW 1234
```

I only need to know if there are any rows where the third column has a number and then also be able to return that number later (I.e I will only get the hits of the two first rows and no hits for the two last rows). I want to ignore the quotes also.

**UPDATE:**
From the comments left to the questions, I realised I left out some important information to solve the issue as the #ROW can have another name that shouldn't be matched, there could be tabs instead of spaces and I also wanted the second and third column to be returned so I combined JCode's and Jan's solutions with the following regexp:

```
#ROW(?:\s+)(\S+)(?:\s+)(\d+|\"\d+\")
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried that isn't working so we may help you.

Comment: Tab separated? If so you could just explode the string on tabs.

Comment: @user3783243: I guess `\d+` *at specific positions* would suffice.

Comment: Jan's code should do everything you want. The `"` is optional and ignored by the `\K`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could test it with

```
^(?:\S+\s+){2}"?\K\d+
```

See an [**example on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vQDyiz/2/).

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex that'll return what you need.

To check if there was a number, just check if there's a value in Group 1.

```
#ROW \d+ (\d+|\"\d+\")
```

Also, I highly suggest using: https://regex101.com/